# AChartEngine graph using two y-axis and x-axis(Datetime)

Tags: android, datetime, charts, achartengine

Having a hard time getting multiple Y axis to show up on a chart using achartengine on android. I have tried to modify what was done on the "Multiple Temperature Chart" demo [**here**](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/MultipleTemperatureChart.java)

I need change X axis for **DateTime**. what needs to be changed in the code example to work with datetime X axis.

Thanks, Rodrigo

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method here would be that on the X axis you should put `Date` timestamps (`long` values). Also, you will have to add custom labels:

```
renderer.addXTextLabel(dateTimestampValue, "custom label");
```

And you will want to hide the default labels:

```
renderer.setXLabels(0);
```